# Grassmannian as a submanifold of the exterior product

Tags: manifolds, exterior-algebra, grassmannian

I'm looking for a proof of the fact that if $V$ is a finitely dimensional vector space, then $G_p(V) \setminus \{0\}$ is a submanifold of $\Lambda_pV$.

Here $G_p(V) = \{ v_1  \wedge ...  \wedge v_p \ | \ v_1, ..., v_p \in V \}$ for $p \ge 1$ and $G_0(V) = \mathbb{K}$.

I know that Grassmannian is a manifold but I don't know how to prove that it is a submanifold of $\Lambda_pV$.

I've found that it can be embedded in the projectivization $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda _k V)$ of $\Lambda _k V$ .

Could this be what I'm after?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That or the unit sphere. See also Plücker coordinates. Any basis $v_1,...,v_p$ of a $p$-dimensional subspace results in the same outer product $v_1∧...∧v_p$, up to a non-zero factor which is the determinant of the transformation matrix. And any factorization of this outer product is a basis of that same subspace. The set of pure products is a sub-manifold in the exterior product that can be described by algebraic equations.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $"0 \in G_p(V)"$, since there is no such thing as $0$ in the Grassmannian of $V$.